# IronPython with Python in Unity: How should I manage dependencies Python-side?

Tags: unity, python

I am currently trying to get Python working in Unity, and I was wondering how would I manage dependencies on the Python end. For example, say I have a Python script with the following dependencies:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 import numpy as np
 import cv2
```

I would like to get these working in IronPython in Unity. Does IronPython have it's own package manager like pip for this, and if so, how would I go about integrating this in Unity? Is there other .dlls for specific packages? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://ironpython.net/blog/2014/12/07/pip-in-ironpython-275.html